# Jquery select value from nested array

Tags: jquery, arrays, getjson

i need to select values from a nested array, here is my code for this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('userdetails.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i,obj){
            $("#placeholder").append('<p>'+obj.firstName+","+obj.lastName+'</p>');
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="placeholder">
<p>line1</p>
<p>line2</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my userdetails.json

```
{"users":[
    {
        "firstName":"user1",
        "lastName":"lastname1",
        "joined": {
            "month":"January",
            "day":12,
            "year":2012
        }
    },
    {
        "firstName":"user2",
        "lastName":"lastname2",
        "joined": {
            "month":"April",
            "day":28,
            "year":2010
        }
    }
]}
```

output:

```
line1
line2
undefined,undefined
```

this is the output which i get but i need to display firstname and lastname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `data.users` instead of `data` to each function. Data is an object which has `array` named `users` which you probably want to iterate.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9F3EK/)**

```
$.each(data.users, function (i, obj) {
    $("#placeholder").append('<p>' + obj.firstName + "," + obj.lastName + '</p>');
});
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer its works. but still i have to change each time in my script. is their exits any other way with out changing my scripts.

Comment: then help me to select the values of month,year,day.